# How can I add a geom_vline of certain dates to my plot if those dates are not present in my original dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart, geom-vline

The gist of what I am trying to do is to overlay dates in which lockdowns came into place and the dates on which they ended. My data contains weekly sales figures but does not contain the dates in which the lockodwns started or ended, thus when I use the "lockdown.end.dates <- which(Unit.sales$Date %in% lockdown.end.dates)" code it turns my "locdown.end.dates" vector into an empty object as it can be seen in the images that I attached.**

This is how my data looks

[image]

This is how my object pane looks when I try to create a vector with dates that are not included in my unit.sales dataframe. Note that for the lockdown.start.date I have tweaked the dates so that they overlap with the ones I have in the unit.sales dataframe

[image]

```
####Install Packages####
library(fpp2)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)

######Load data########

        Unit.sales <- structure(list(
  Date = c(
    "30/03/2019",
    "06/04/2019",
    "13/04/2019",
    "20/04/2019",
    "27/04/2019",
    "04/05/2019",
    "11/05/2019",
    "18/05/2019",
    "25/05/2019",
    "01/06/2019"
  ),
  Units = c(
    967053.4,
    633226.9,
    523264,
    473914.2,
    418087.5,
    504342.2,
    477819,
    415650,
    406972.3,
    429791.4
  )
),
row.names = c(NA, 10L),
class = "data.frame")

######Convert date column to date format########

Unit.sales$Date <- as.Date(Unit.sales$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')

######Convert data frame to time series object#####

unit.sales.ts <- xts(Unit.sales$Units, Unit.sales$Date)

class(unit.sales.ts)

#######Visualize data######

unit.sales.plot <- Unit.sales %>% ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Units)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b %y",date_breaks  ="2 month") +
  labs(title = "Linechart of unit sales")

#Create objects containing the lockdown dates#

lockdown.start.dates <- as.Date(c("2020-03-28", "2020-11-07", "2021-01-09"))

lockdown.start.dates <- which(Unit.sales$Date %in% lockdown.start.dates)

lockdown.end.dates <- as.Date(c("2020-06-15", "2020-11-05", "2021-04-12"))

lockdown.end.dates <- which(Unit.sales$Date %in% lockdown.end.dates)

#Add lockdown dates to the unit.sales.plot#

unit.sales.plot + 
geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(Unit.sales$Date[lockdown.start.dates,]),
                             col = "red", lwd = 3)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post data as an image because we cannot copy/paste that into R for testing.

Comment: I`m sorry about that and thank you for taking the time to reply. I`m new to R and this website so I don`t quite know how to do it but I`ll look into how to update it now :)